# How can i integrate country_select gem with best_in_place editing

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, inline-editing, best-in-place

I am using the [best_in_place](https://github.com/bernat/best_in_place) gem to edit records inline and [country_select](https://github.com/purcell/country-select) to render a list of countries to select from. When using best_in_place to edit a select field i do this:

```
<%= best_in_place(@home, :country_name, :type => :select, :collection => [[1, "Spain"], [2, "Italy"]]) %>
```

Now i like to get a list of all the countries that country_select has and pass that into the collection parameter.
The country_select gem provides a simple helper to render the select field:

```
<%= country_select("home", "country_name") %>
```

I would like to replace the :collection parameter in best_in_place helper to include the list of countries provided by country_select. I know that best_in_place expects the [[key, value], [key, value],...] input into :collection, but i am not sure how to do this. Please advise. Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just do the following and it will work:

```
<%= best_in_place @home, :country, type: :select, collection: (ActionView::Helpers::FormOptionsHelper::COUNTRIES.zip(ActionView::Helpers::FormOptionsHelper::COUNTRIES)) %>
```

Comment: thanks, it works like a charm. if possible could you explain the collection part stuff, i don't understand why it works.

Comment: The country gem is located inside of ActionView::Helpers. If you check the code from that gem, you will see that it enclosed in the ActionView, Helpers and FormOptionsHelper. So, if you want to get access to the COUNTRIES constant, you need to add all of that API.

The zip method is a method from Array. It just adds the previous element into an array.

Answer (score 1):

In Rails 5.2, assuming you have the Countries gem, you should do:

```
<%= best_in_place @home, :country, type: :select, collection: ISO3166::Country.all_names_with_codes.fix_for_bip, place_holder: @home.country %>
```

The fix_for_bip is a custom function I've inserted into the Array class, because best_in_place requires all select box arrays to be served in the opposite order from regular select boxes: for a regular Rails select, you'd give an array of `[["Spain", "ES"], ["Sri Lanka", "SR"], ["Sudan", "SD"]...]` (first what the user sees, then the option value). So this is what the Countries gem returns. However, `best_in_place collection:` only accepts the reverse kind of array: `[["ES", "Spain"], ["SR", "Sri Lanka"], ["SD", "Sudan"]]`. It also has a problem when not all array items are themselves two-item arrays - something that Rails select boxes deal with automatically. So I created a fix_for_bip function that I call on all of my arrays when feeding them to best_in_place:

```
class Array
  def fix_for_bip
    self.map { |e| e.is_a?(Array) ? e.reverse : [e, e] }
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using rails 4 a few years later , this does the trick:

```
<%= best_in_place @cart.order, :country_name, type: :select, :collection =>  ActionView::Helpers::FormOptionsHelper::COUNTRIES%>
```