# How to extract the list of countries into an array from country_select gem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, x-editable

I'm trying to extract a list of all country names and place them into an array from the [country_select gem](https://github.com/stefanpenner/country_select). It's very clear how to take advantage of this gem when it comes to adding a select field inside a form doing:

```
<%= form_for User.new, url: root_url do |f| %>
  <%= f.country_select :country_code %>
<% end %>
```

But what if I need to use that same country list outside of a form. In my case I'm using [X-editable-rails gem](https://github.com/werein/x-editable-rails) for inline editing. My objective is to make inline edition available for a country attribute. To do that I'll have to specify the source of a select list as below:

```
<%= editable @waiter, :country, type: :select, title: 'Your country', source: ["Country_1", "Country_2", "Country_n"] %>
```

However, I can't come up with a way to extract that list and put it inside a variable.

I've tried these two suggested ways in this [stack overflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10243683/how-can-i-integrate-country-select-gem-with-best-in-place-editing):

```
@countries = ActionView::Helpers::FormOptionsHelper::COUNTRIES.zip(ActionView::Helpers::FormOptionsHelper::COUNTRIES)
```

and

```
<%= @countries = ActionView::Helpers::FormOptionsHelper::COUNTRIES %>
```

Could anyone help on how to achieve this?

Comment: Try inspecting `@countries` and check what it returns. Also inspect the editable field in the browser and paste the *HTML* that produced for that field in the console.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`country_select` gem has [`countries`](https://github.com/hexorx/countries) gem as a dependency. The gem provides finders and other useful methods for working with countries.

`ISO3166::Country.all_translated` might be the method you're looking for.

Comment: Thanks a lot Igor. Exactly what I was looking for.